# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<>>

Tags: c#, async-await

I am getting an exception.

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<IntegraPay.Domain.SObjects.Industry>'` to `'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IntegraPay.Domain.SObjects.Industry>>'`

Below is my property and method.

```
  private List<WebFormFieldContent> WebFormFields { get; set; } = 
       new List<WebFormFieldContent>();

  Task<IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>> IRegistrationRepository.GetWebFormFields()
        {
            return WebFormFields;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you expect this code to work (and what exactly you want to achieve)?

Comment: Why are you returning a `Task<>` in the first place? Either go async or return a `IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>`. I feel there is a bit of a lack in understanding of what exactly async code is.

Comment: Thats my question. Why it is not working.

Comment: Your current sample is essentially the same as `string Foo(){return 42;}` which would fail with the same error... It is quite hard to understand what exact piece of knowledge you are looking for. You may want to read on how `async` changes code generated for method (i.e. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/c-async-what-is-it,-and-how-does-it-work/ ).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This error typically happens when you are missing `async` in the method declaration.

When you put `async` in the signature, C# compiler adds "magic" to do the conversion from an object to a `Task<T>` returning that object.

However, in your situation `async` is unnecessary, because you return a task with a result that you already have:

```
return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>>(
    WebFormFields
);
```

Comment: It works only if I use await and async in the method. If I remove them I getCannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<WebFormFieldContent>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>>'

Comment: @maxspan I'm sorry I missed the type mismatch. Adding an explicit type should fix this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your method return type is

```
Task<IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>>
```

but the implementation returns a

```
List<WebFormFieldContent>.
```

You can change it to

```
Task<List<WebFormFieldContent>> IRegistrationRepository.GetWebFormFields()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(WebFormFields);
    }
```

Or change the private variable to

```
IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent> WebFormFields { get; set; } = 
   new List<WebFormFieldContent>();
```

type.

Or you can add an async key word to make it a synchronous call

```
async Task<IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>> IRegistrationRepository.GetWebFormFields()
    {
        return WebFormFields;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that's another option.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<WebFormFieldContent>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>>'

Comment: @StephenZeng should be failing the same way after your edit - you need explicit type like `Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<WebFormFieldContent>>(WebFormFields);`