# SQLite-net-pcl, how to return query in method

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

My project is in xamarin.
I create class call "DataBaseService", one of method in this class should return all value from table as a "List". This method is call from other class where I have instance class "DataBaseService".

But I have a problem with this method. I can't return a list.

```
public async Task<List<Note>> getNotes()
    {
        var a = await _dbConnect.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();

        return a;
    }
```

List of errors:

> 1.Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'Task>' is less accessible than method 'DataBaseService.getNotes()'
>
> 2. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>      to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.

Can someone tell me how this method should be write?

Thank you.

Comment: are you call getNotes() method using await like await getNotes();?

Comment: What a stupid mistake I did. I didn't use "await". Now it works. Thank you so much. Regards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579354/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-collections-generic-list-to-system-th)